# Encrypt / decrypt XOR with using the alphabet characters

Tags: c++, encryption, cryptography, xor

I wrote simple program that should encrypt and decrypt message XOR cipher.
I limited range to the characters of the alphabet (small characters).
Encryption works OK, but after decrypting message doesn't match.
If I run the program without restriction to the alphabet (without this %26 + 97), it works ok.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    char message[7] = "string";
    char key[5] = "abcd";
    char encrypted[7];

    size_t sizeTab = strlen(message);

    cout << sizeTab << endl;

    cout << "ENCRYPTION" << endl;
    int i = 0;
    do{
        encrypted[i] = ((message[i] ^ key[i%4])%26 + 97);
    }while(i++ < sizeTab - 1);

    encrypted[sizeTab] = '\0';

    cout << encrypted << endl;

    cout << "DECRYPTION" << endl;
    i = 0;
    do{
        encrypted[i] = ((encrypted[i] ^ key[i%4])%26 + 97); 
    }while(i++ < sizeTab - 1);

    cout << encrypted << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

For example if I have message on entry: **string**
After encryption: **swrnpf**
After decryption: **svrkre**

What I do wrong, what I should correct?
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

> If I run the program without restriction to the alphabet (without this %26 + 97), it works ok.

That's because the `%26 + 97` part is wrong. The modulo operation loses information, which makes it impossible to correctly decrypt the message again.

Maybe what you're looking for instead is the [Vigenère cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher) ? With it, you can keep the ciphertext in the same alphabet as the plaintext (which seems to be what you're trying to achieve), and still be very similar to your approach.

Comment: Correct. There is not even a single plaintext-key-combination which is unique reversible...

Comment: Thanks for help! I understand where is mistake.